# Hibernate: get entire hierarchy with filtered child collections

Tags: hibernate, hql

i'm using hibernate and would like to get the entire hierarchy of Users->Posts->Comments but only the comments that have "status" to true.

i've tried something like this:

```
Select user from User user join user.posts post join post.comments comment where comment.status = true
```

But this give me an explosion of user for the number of comments with status true and inside the single user->post, i've all the comments, non only the ones with status true.

I've also tried with "left join" or "inner join" but i get the same result.

Is there a way to get what i would like? and wich is the "cleaner" way to do this?

Here is a little example of the class structure:

```
Class User
 List<Post> posts

Class Post
 List<Comment> comments

Class Comment
 String text
 boolean status
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is filter the collection using the **@FilterJoinTable** annotation:

```
@FilterJoinTable(name="activeComments", condition="status = :status")
List<Comment> comments
```

You will need to declare the filter at the class level:

```
@FilterDef(name="activeComments", parameters={
    @ParamDef( name="status", type="boolean" )
})
```

and enable it from the session:

```
    Filter filter = session.enableFilter("activeComments");
    filter.setParameter("status", true);
```

Here is a tutorial on Hibernate filtering, with examples:
http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-filter-and-filterjointable-annotation-example

...and the official Hibernate 3 documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html